# react native my image got cut off in styling

Tags: reactjs, native

this is my carddetail.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View,Text, Image, Dimensions} from "react-native";

import Item from "./Item";
import ItemSection from "./ItemSection";

const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const imageHeight = (30 / 100) * height; // calculates 30% of the screen

const CardDetail = ({brand}) => {
    const {headerContainer, headerText, imageStyle} = styles;

    return( 
            <Item>
                <ItemSection>
                    <View style={headerContainer}>
                        <Text style={headerText}>{brand.brand}</Text>
                        <Text style ={headerText}>{brand.model[0].name}</Text>  
                    </View>
                    </ItemSection>
               <ItemSection>
                    <Image
                    style={imageStyle}
                    source={{ uri:brand.model[0].image}}
                    />        
                    
                </ItemSection>
                
             </Item>

             
    );

};

const styles ={
    headerContainer:{
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        flex: 1

    },
    headerText:{
        fontSize: 18,
        flex: 1,
        fontWeight: "500",
        textTransform: "uppercase",
        flexDirection: "column"

    },
    imageStyle: {
        height: 300,
        flex:1,
        width: 0
       
    }


}

export default CardDetail;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8HG9.png)

i already using flex and i did some surfing but i didnt know whats wrong with my code

im using react native 0.68.02 version

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: sorrry the  quetion is how could i fix my cut off image in react native i already using flex but it got cut off

Comment: Could you please include an image, so that it is possible to retrace what the output looks like?

Comment: i did upload an image u can check ini here https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8HG9.png

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the following configuration:

```
imageStyle: {
    height: 300,
    flex:1,
    width: 0
}
```

When setting width to 0, it is likely the image doesn't even show.

Comment: na its not that i even delete the width nothing change cause im using the flex command